# CRUD con Ajax no guarda dato de tipo "date"

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, ajax, datatables

Estoy teniendo problemas en un CRUD para guardar valores de tipo "date" de un formulario. Otros valores de tipo number o text los guarda perfectamente pero el de tipo fecha no lo acepta.
Asi es como recoge los datos:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="companyName" class="col-form-label">Company Name:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="companyName">
</div>                
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="fecha_subida" class="col-form-label">Fecha Subida:</label>
  <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fecha_subida">
</div> 
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="precio" class="col-form-label">Precio:</label>
   <input type="number" class="form-control" id="precio">
</div>
```

Este es el parte .js que procesa el formulario:

```
$(document).on("click", ".btnEditar", function(){
    ...
    companyName = fila.find('td:eq(2)').text();
    fechaSubida = fila.find('td:eq(3)').text();
    precio = parseInt(fila.find('td:eq(5)').text());
   ...
   $("#companyName").val(companyName);
   $("#fecha_subida").val(fechaSubida);
   $("#precio").val(precio);
   ...
$("#formVentas").submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();    

companyName = $.trim($("#companyName").val());
fechaSubida = $.trim($("#fecha_subida").val()); 
precio = $.trim($("#precio").val());

$.ajax({
    url: "bd/crud_ventas.php",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { companyName:companyName, fechaSubida:fechaSubida, precio:precio, id:id, opcion:opcion},
    success: function(data){  
        console.log(data);
        id = data[0].id;            
        nombre = data[0].nombre;
        fechaSubida = data[0].fechaSubida;
        precio = data[0].precio;
        if(opcion == 1){tablaVentas.row.add([companyName,fechaSubida,precio]).draw();}
        else{tablaVentas.row(fila).data([companyName,fechaSubida,precio]).draw();}            
    }        
   
 }
```

Todo esto se manda a un crud que procesa los datos. Esa parte no la incluyo porque funciona. Yo creo que el problema reside en que al recoger los datos de fecha los manda por ajax como un string y al recibir la bd este string lo rechaza por no tener un formato "date". En la bd el tipo de formato es "date".

El mensaje de error que manda es:

"DataTables warning: table id=tablaVentas - Requested unknown parameter '3' for row 3, column 3. For more information about this error, please see [http://datatables.net/tn/4"](http://datatables.net/tn/4%22)

El error hace referencia a la columna que contiene el date (aqui no coincide porque se omitieron columnas para no alargar el mensaje).

¿Existe alguna manera de "parsear" un campo tipo date al igual que se hace con el de tipo number para que no rechaze la fecha introducida y la guarde en la bd?

Este es el php:

```
$companyName = (isset($_POST['companyName'])) ? $_POST['companyName'] : '';
$fechaSubida = (isset($_POST['fecha_subida'])) ? $_POST['fecha_subida'] : '';
$precio = (isset($_POST['precio'])) ? $_POST['precio'] : '';
$opcion = (isset($_POST['opcion'])) ? $_POST['opcion'] : '';
$id = (isset($_POST['id'])) ? $_POST['id'] : '';

switch($opcion){
    case 1: //alta
        $consulta = "INSERT INTO ventas_log ( companyName, fecha_subida,, precio) VALUES('$companyName', '$fechaSubida', '$precio' ) ";         
        $resultado = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
        $resultado->execute(); 
        $consulta = "SELECT id, companyName, fecha_subida,  precio FROM ventas_log ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
        $resultado = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
        $resultado->execute();
        $data=$resultado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        break;

print json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); 
$conexion = NULL;
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133133/discussion-on-question-by-ricardokra-crud-con-ajax-no-guarda-dato-de-tipo-date).

Answer (score 1):

Hay varios errores, uno tipográfico en el crud en PHP proporcionado y un par en la parte del `success` del ajax.

Esto recogia mal el valor de `fechaSubida` proporcionado por la función ajax:

```
$fechaSubida = (isset($_POST['fecha_subida'])) ? $_POST['fecha_subida'] : '';
```

Lo correcto es esto:

```
$fechaSubida = (isset($_POST['fechaSubida'])) ? $_POST['fechaSubida'] : '';
```

debido que el dato proporcionado venia de aquí en la parte de ajax:

```
data: { companyName:companyName, fechaSubida:fechaSubida, precio:precio, id:id, opcion:opcion},
```

Luego, en la parte del success, esto parece incorrecto:

```
nombre = data[0].nombre;
fechaSubida = data[0].fechaSubida;
```

pues los valores creo que los saca de aqui:

```
$consulta = "SELECT id, companyName, fecha_subida, precio FROM ventas_log ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
```

y si te fijas, los campos devueltos, que luego iran en el json, se llaman **companyName** y **fecha_subida**, y en cambio en el ajax de vuelta esperas que se llamen **nombre** y **fechaSubida** por lo tanto una posible solucion seria esta:

```
nombre = data[0].companyName;
fechaSubida = data[0].fecha_subida;
```

Prueba y nos cuentas.

Comment: si es un error tipografico, la pregunta se cierra como error tipografico!

Comment: Si, lo se, pero aun no es definitivo, el error sigue alli, lo estamos gestionando en el chat, y si te fijas en el principio ya lo digo que es "para que conste" por si otro lo pone como si fuera una solución real... Aun asi ahora se ha ido del chat y no se si ha visto mi ultima peticion, je (habia tenido que salir un rato)

Comment: Ale, ya he ampliado mi respuesta... ya no es tan tipográfica como antes, pues he visto inconsistencias en su uso de los valores pasados, pero falta que el OP lo verifique